# android studio error comes when try to luanch avd in the emulator

Tags: react-native, android-studio

**Unable to locate abd.exe**

when i want to launch avd in the emulator error message such as comes
"unable to locate abd"
abd.exe file exist already in platform tools

Comment: Did you add it to your PATH variable?

Comment: wihice one "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" or "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools"

Comment: I added the first one as a system variable name ANDROID_HOME

Comment: You need to add the second one to the PATH environment variable.